# How do I change the background of an element to a different drawable?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I want to make a `textView` that turns green with a positive number, red with a negative number, and goes invisible when 0. I have two separate drawables for each background.

I have changed `updateView.setDrawable(@Drawable/add_background)` to `updateView.setDrawable(R.drawable.add_background)`, and am now getting the error `'setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in 'android.view.View' cannot be applied to '(int)'`

Here is the code:

```
Integer team1UpdateAmount = 0;


TextView updateView = findViewById(R.id.team1UpdateView);
    if (team1UpdateAmount == 0) {updateView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); return;}

    updateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (team1UpdateAmount > 0) {
        updateView.setText("+" + team1UpdateAmount);
        updateView.setBackground(R.drawable.add_background);
    }
    if (team1UpdateAmount < 0) {
        updateView.setText("" + team1UpdateAmount);
        updateView.setBackground(R.drawable.sub_background);
    }
```

Comment: You should add more information like the whole error message, and all relevant source code in a form of minimal reproducible example. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What type does `setBackground` take and what type is `R.drawable.add_background`? If you don't understand why that doesn't work, I would recommend you spend time learning Java by itself outside of Android.

Comment: @dominicoder it takes a `Drawable`, I'm giving it an `Integer`. I don't get how the drawable file is an `Integer` and not a `Drawable`

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) on the topic?

Comment: The android documentation is really hard to understand and kind of sucks in general, but it's probably worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this line

```
updateView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sub_background)
```

thats how you are referencing to resources in code, referencing by `@` is for XMLs

Comment: I got the error of `'setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in 'android.view.View' cannot be applied to '(int)'`

Comment: check out [`setBackgroundResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int))

Comment: I just tested this again, the reason I got that error because I didn't change `setBackground` to `setBackgroundResource`.

Answer (score 0):

While experimenting, I found the answer.

I set `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_background)` to a variable called `addBackground` (same with sub), and referred to that variable in `updateView.setBackground(addBackground)`

The code now looks like this:

```
Drawable addBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_background);
Drawable subBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sub_background);
TextView updateView = findViewById(R.id.Team1UpdateView);

if (team1UpdateAmount == 0) {updateView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); return;}


        updateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (team1UpdateAmount > 0) {
            updateView.setText("+" + team1UpdateAmount);
            updateView.setBackground(addBackground);
        }
        if (team1UpdateAmount < 0) {
            updateView.setText("" + team1UpdateAmount);
            updateView.setBackground(subBackground);
        }
```

Comment: Good. There's also [the version that takes a drawable resource ID directly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)). Make sure to review the documentation and search for similarly named methods when trying to find the one you need.